# IP camera to NVR with RTSP not working if DMZ not actived

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, camera

I have a [TP-Link VIGI NVR1008H](https://www.tp-link.com/ae/business-networking/vigi-network-video-recorder/vigi-nvr1008h/) recorder and 2 cameras connected over RTSP wireless on wan (other network). The cameras uses ports 40000 and 40001. I opened the ports for the NVR on my network, but it's not working

If I activate the DMZ for the NVR all works, so a port is closed, but I am not sure which one. What can I do to check which port I need to open for my NVR to work without the DMZ?

If I don't find it, is it OK to have the NVR on DMZ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i need to know what port i have to open for my nvr to work without the dmz actived

Comment: Welcome to the community. I edited your question for clarity - please verify and correct if I made mistakes. If you want to add more info, please don't answer in comments but [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1767867/edit) the question instead so the relevant info is readily available for the community. I'd suggest taking the quick [Tour](https://superuser.com/tour) and checking the Asking- and Answering -sections in the [Help](https://superuser.com/help) to find out how the site works.

Comment: Wireshark could likely identify the port. We can't tell you which port you need.  Having cameras on your network with DMZ enabled is a horrible idea. To be frank I wouldn't make them accessible unless you were connected to a VPN